# Finding items in quotes, but not escaped quotes, in python using re

Tags: python, regex

Suppose there is a series of strings. Important items are enclosed in quotes, but other items are enclosed in escaped quotes. How can you return only the important items?

Example where both are returned:

```
import re
testString = 'this, is a test "one" it should only return the first item \"two\" and not the second'
pattern = = '"([^\\\"]*)"'
print re.findall( pattern, testString)
```

Result prints
`['one', 'two']`

How can I get python's re to only print
`['one']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [negative lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to ensure there's no backslash before the quote:

```
import re
testString = r'this, is a test "one" it should only return the first item \"two\" and not the second'
pattern = r'(?<!\\)"([^"]*)(?<!\\)"'
          # ^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^
print re.findall(pattern, testString)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/lV6zF6/1)

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/4HIxiO)

Answer (score 0):

Here even though you are using \" to mark other items but in python it is interpreted as "two" only.You can use python raw strings where \" will be treated as \"

```
import re
testString = r'this, is a  test "one" it should only return the first item \"two\" and not the second'
pattern = '"(\w*)"'
print re.findall( pattern, testString)
```